# SAX error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to InputSource

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon, tag-soup

Relevant code; barfs on instantiating the `SAXSource`:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
XMLReader xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader("org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser");
Source input = new SAXSource(xmlReader, "http://books.toscrape.com/");
Result output = new StreamResult(System.out);
factory.newTransformer().transform(input, output);
```

The JavaDoc's [say](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/sax/SAXSource.html#SAXSource(org.xml.sax.XMLReader,%20org.xml.sax.InputSource)):

```
public SAXSource(XMLReader reader,
         InputSource inputSource)
```

> Create a SAXSource, using an XMLReader and a SAX InputSource. The
>   Transformer or SAXTransformerFactory will set itself to be the
>   reader's ContentHandler, and then will call reader.parse(inputSource).

Looking at `InputSource` shows:

```
InputSource(InputStream byteStream)
Create a new input source with a byte stream.
InputSource(Reader characterStream)
Create a new input source with a character stream.
```

So this would entail, for [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html), a character stream to read in `html` for the `InputStream`??

Would `tagsoup` better be used for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54033869/262852) identity transform?  But, how?

Comment: You can use a `URLConnection` which has a getter for an ``InputStream`` that represents the resource behind that url.

Comment: that's much more practical, thanks.

Comment: i put the code into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a constructor https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html#InputSource-java.lang.String- that takes a system id e.g. a URL so you can use `Source input = new SAXSource(xmlReader, new InputSource("http://books.toscrape.com/"));`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to an InputStream that reads from the resource behind the URL like this:

```
InputStream i = new URL("http://...").openConnection().getInputStream();
```

Then you can use `i` for your `SAXSource`.

Comment: You can do this, but unless you think you're smarter than the guys who wrote the XML parser in terms of managing HTTP connections, then it's easier to just do `new InputSource("http://....")`

Comment: I don't think that :) But it's a way of making it work.